# Retrieving the Payee details of a payment via Xero API

Tags: xero-api

I am trying to retrieve the Payee details of payments for a bank transaction.  This information lives in the bank feed and also in the History of a transaction after it's been reconciled.

The only option I have found is the bankfeeds scope which isn't available to me
https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/bankfeeds/overview#access

Has anyone found a way to get this information out via API (xero or via their banks API)

I have accessed the API and tried all available scopes without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to retrieve the details of the bank statement line itself as this needs the bank feeds scope which is restricted but you can make a GET request to the bank transactions endpoint to see the contact that it has been attributed to in Xero.

You need the accounting.transactions or accounting.transactions.read scope.

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/banktransactions

Comment: Thanks for the input, it looks like this is the closest i can get.

Comment: For anyone else that needs this, the PAYEE details are stored in the History of the Bank Transaction after it's reconciled.